# Can Nutch be deployed to crawl specific pages

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Can Nutch be used to:

1. Create a web service which I can give a list of urls to (these could be in batches of tens of thousands) -- this could be a simple wrapper around a command line
2. Check repeatedly if the job was complete -- this could be a simple wrapper around a command line
3. in return: get a dataset which has the dumped html pages -- this could be a simple wrapper around a command line

Answer (score 2):

The other thing to note here is that you can also check out this [Qurora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-better-Scrapy-or-Apache-Nutch/answer/Chris-Mattmann) where I describe how to enable focused crawling in Nutch.

> Not sure why my first answer didn't post, but I wanted to address
>   this. Nutch doesn't have to be batch mode. The bin/crawl script is
>   batch, however, you can call all of the interim steps for Nutch
>   (inject, generate, fetch, parse, dedup, updatedb, etc.) incrementally
>   and Nutch has had these capabilities for a while.
>
> In addition, Nutch has had scoring plugins for quite a while, and has
>   supported things like Adaptive Fetch schedules, and all of the Nutch
>   data is in databases and so forth that are interrogated through the
>   command line tools, Java, and now there is an emerging REST interface
>   and also work to create a Python client for this as well.
>
> My team at NASA JPL is working to improve Nutch through the DARPA
>   Memex project. Nutch uses Tika to handle 1200+ and growing file
>   formats (detection, parsing, entity extraction, etc.) We also have
>   emerging plugins for Naive Bayes focused crawling, Cosine Similarity
>   scoring and other capabilities to really make Nutch both a broad and
>   focused crawler. The Naive Bayes directly integrates Mahout into
>   Nutch. These are present in 1.11-trunk.
>
> Further, Nutch also integrates Selenium for Deep Web/Ajax/Javascript
>   crawling, and there are lots of improvements coming and already
>   present in Nutch to make it a good choice as well.
>
> HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do this using Apache Nutch.

Have a look at the Nutch REST API [0] (actively in development) which can allow you to start Nutch as a service, provide URLs via a HTTP call, monitor the completion of jobs and then dump the data back.

[0] - https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch_1.X_RESTAPI